# WatchKit data not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm passing data from iOS to WatchKit.  **I can't get the data to show that was received on the WatchKit side** somehow though.

This works fine: iOS `TableViewController`

```
func getCloudKit() {
    ///...
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { // There is no error
            for play in results! {
                let newPlay = Play()
                    newPlay.tColor = play["TColor"] as! String

                do {
                    try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["color" : newPlay.tColor])
                    NSLog("NewPColor: %@", newPlay.tColor)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                self.objects.append(newPlay)
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't calling any of the `NSLog`s or showing any of the data: WatchKit `InterfaceController`

```
import WatchConnectivity


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var colorLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil

    private func configureWCSession() {
        session?.delegate = self;
        session?.activateSession()
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        configureWCSession()
    }

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
    }

    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let colorWatch = applicationContext["color"] as? String
        NSLog("Check if anything here: %@", colorWatch!)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if let colorWatch = colorWatch {
                        self.colorLabel.setText("From iPhone: \(colorWatch)")
                        NSLog("Heres all the strings %@", colorWatch)
                    } else {
                        NSLog("Nothing")
                    }
                }
    }


}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What is WatchSessionManager, and does it make sure to set up WCSession and activate it?

Comment: `WatchSessionManager` is a singleton class to set up WCSession and activate it.  That is on the iOS side, so that part works perfectly when I log everything.  The WatchKit side is the one not working great.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is session in configureWCSession() nil perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, maybe, how would you double check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking if session is nil with something like (my swift foo is weak):

```
  private func configureWCSession() {
    print("session: \(session?))
    session?.delegate = self;
    session?.activateSession()
}
```

Comment: I did  `print("session: \(session)")`  and it gave me   ` session: Optional(<WCSession: 0x7c045f30, sessionActivated: NO, hasDelegate: NO>)` so I think you're on to something right?

Comment: Hmmm... Try adding the print("session... after the call to activateSession. What does it then print?

Comment: Yeah it works after the `activateSession()`: "session: Optional(<WCSession: 0x7bf61a10, sessionActivated: YES, hasDelegate: YES>)"

Comment: on the watch side is session.reachable true? It's not needed for applicationContext but might provide a clue

Comment: Looks like it is true.  I did this `if (session?.reachable != nil) {
            NSLog("Yes")
        }` and it `NSLog`ged "Yes".

Comment: Reachable is a BOOL, so you should be doing if (session?.reachable) { NSLog("yes") } else { NSLog("NO") }

Comment: Hmm.  It gave me an error when I didn't use `!= nil` at first.  And then the error gave me the suggestion to change it by adding `!= nil`.  So its not letting me do `        if (session?.reachable) {
            NSLog("Yes")
        } else {
            NSLog("No")
        }'

Comment: Try replacing "if (session?.reachable)" with "if (session!.reachable)"

Comment: Ok I will try that out here